# Must Primefaces Data Exporter target be an absolute id?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, java-ee-6

I am trying to use Prime Faces data exporter component:

```
<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="table_name" fileName="summaries"/>
```

It would seem that the target attribute needs to point to the id of a data table.  On my page I have a composite component which gets included twice.  It takes one parameter which tells it where to get its data from.  So the composite component renders the same table twice, but with different data.

I want the exporter for both tables.  In my composite component I have:

```
<p:dataTable id="overview"
```

Of course when this is rendered twice JSF generates the id dynamically e.g.

```
form:tabView:j_id1693604892_4df53909:overview
```

Is there any way I can get the Prime Faces data exporter to work in this circumstance ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure at all that it will work , but try `target="@(.myTableClass)"` where `<p:dataTable styleClass="myTableClass"` ... http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Code from DataExporter.java (Primefaces source simplified)

```
String tableId = (String) target.getValue(elContext);

Exporter exporter = ExporterFactory.getExporterForType(exportAs);

UIComponent component = event.getComponent().findComponent(tableId);

if(component == null) {
    throw new FacesException("Cannot find component \"" + tableId + "\" in view.");
}

if(!(component instanceof DataTable)) {
    throw new FacesException("Unsupported datasource target:\"" + component.getClass().getName() + "\", exporter must target a PrimeFaces DataTable.");
}

DataTable table = (DataTable) component;
exporter.export(context, table, outputFileName, isPageOnly, isSelectionOnly, encodingType, preProcessor, postProcessor);
```

So multiple components not supported.

What you can try:

1. Passing datatable id as a seperate parameter to your composite component.
2. Giving id to your composite component. It prepends this id to its child components becuse it is a naming container. This way you can reference it anyway you want.

Comment: 1) id cannot be set dynamically on component i.e. id attribute doesn't support EL

2) i had tried adding the id to the composite component.  If I look in the rendered html the div around the <table> has an id of "form:tabView:compcomponentid:tableid" but primefaces just complains it cannot find the table with this id

Comment: 1. i never said "set it dynamically"!!? 2. give different static ids to every composite component for example : myComponent1 myComponent2 this way your generated ids should look like this "form:tabView:myComponent1:tableid" "form:tabView:myComponent2:tableid". BTW please share a little bit more code. I don't know how you type ids.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how I can generate a pdf for multiple data tables using primefaces. I would appreciate some help